# Connect multiple JCR repositories to one database (and keep updated)

Tags: java, mysql, database, jackrabbit, jcr

I am a little bit stuck in the moment because I don't know if my problem is solvable at all.

I have one database (MySQL) where a JCR repo is stored.

Secondly do I have two webapps (edit/live) that share this data. Live is designed to read only, so it can (really??) be considered save regarding concurrency.

My problem is that everything works well as long as no existing node is modified. If an existing node is changed, saved, session closed and I display that node content on the "live"-side it's still the old content. On the "edit"-side it's all ok.

The problem seems that JCR (Jackrabbit) doesn't get the changes on the underlying database and serves cached content.

My question is: Is that problem solvable and when yes what steps are needed?

I hope I could explain my problem so anyone could hint me on this.

Thanks a lot in advance,
flo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. Problem solved. The magic word is clustering.

After configuring clusters on each JCR repository instance everything works fine.

For further information: http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/Clustering